# how can I solve this problem "Java undefined" ? I already have java install in system and path set?

Tags: octave

```
b=java.util.LinkedList;
li=b.listIterator;
```

> > b=java.util.LinkedList;

error: 'java' undefined near line 1 column 3

> > li=b.listIterator;

error: 'b' undefined near line 1 column 4

> > bx=java.util.LinkedList;

Comment: I am running this code in octave

Answer (score 2):

Read the Octave Manual's chapter on [interfacing with Java](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Java-Interface.html#Java-Interface). Note that octave uses a very different way of interfacing with Java compared to Matlab. This may be partly because Matlab is built on Java, which presumably allows it to use this natively. Whereas octave is built on C++, and therefore relies on this different interface.

Effectively your code should be:

```
b  = javaObject( "java.util.LinkedList" );
li = java_get( b, "listIterator" );
```

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem!

Comment: "This may be partly because Matlab is built on Java, which presumably allows it to use this natively." Not the case: Just the GUI bits and some Toolbox stuff of Matlab are built in Java; Matlab itself is written in C/C++/Fortran. The issue is that Octave's M-code parser doesn't have support for resolving dot-reference syntax to Java class references. There's a bug open for this on Savannah; I can't find it at the moment, though. Also note that the "javaObject"/"javaMethod" syntax is supported by Matlab, too. And the `b.listIterator` syntax should work in Octave once `b` holds a Java object.

Comment: it's with lowercase: javaObject()